# Trouble creating a form with a table of nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a `Report` with many nested `Value` objects:

Report class

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comments
  has_many :values
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :values
end
```

Value class

```
class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value, :assessed_user_id, :behaviour_id

  belongs_to :assessed_user
  belongs_to :behaviour

  belongs_to :report

end
```

I need a form that will accept a `Report` with its associated matrix of `Value` objects like so:

```
| User | Behaviour1 | Behaviour2 | Behaviour3 |
| Bob  |     ___    |    ___     |    ___     |
| Jane |     ___    |    ___     |    ___     |
| Jill |     ___    |    ___     |    ___     |
```

I'm new to rails and I've read all about nested attributes and I've tried a million variations on `semantic_form_for` and possibilities with formtastic, but I cannot seem to place the proper `value.value` objects in their right places or to set their `behaviour` and `assessed_user` as hidden fields, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

The following shows what are supposed to be hidden fields and I cannot get my create (follows) to accept it. Also, I don't see any indexes on the sub-form elements:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @report do |f| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>User</th>
    <% @behaviours.each do |behaviour| %>
      <th><%= behaviour.name %></th>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% index = 0 %>
    <% @members.each do |member| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= member.first_name %> <%= member.last_name %></td>
        <% @behaviours.each do |behaviour| %>
          <% @report.values[index].behaviour_id = behaviour.id %>
          <% @report.values[index].assessed_user_id = member.id %>
          <td>

              <%= f.inputs :behaviour_id, :as => :hidden, :for => @report.values[index] %>
              <%= f.inputs :assessed_user_id, :as => :hidden, :for => @report.values[index] %>
              <%= f.inputs :value, :for => :values, :for => @report.values[index] %>
              <% index = index + 1  %>
          </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>  

  </table>
  <%= f.inputs :comments %>

  <%= f.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

reports_controller.rb

```
def create
  @report = Report.new( params[:report] )
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look on this Railscate esp 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Watching the video gave me a better understanding and, while I am not doing quite the same thing they are, it showed me a lot of the basics that I didn't thoroughly understand. Now I'm using the basic, more primitive versions of it all. While it's not really the answer, it did send me in a good direction.